# VBA Array - subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, vba

I'm hoping to create a VBA array with 5 rows and 2 columns

```
varData = [{0, 0; 0, 0; 0, 0; 0, 0; 0, 0}]
```

and change the values according to a case

```
select Case sth
                Case "1"
                    varData(0, 0) = varData(0, 0) + Cells(I, 1).Value
                Case "2"
                    varData(0, 1) = varData(0, 1) + Cells(I, 1).Value
                Case "3"
                    varData(0, 2) = varData(0, 2) + Cells(I, 1).Value
                Case "4"
                    varData(0, 3) = varData(0, 3) + Cells(I, 1).Value
                Case "5"
                    varData(0, 4) = varData(0, 4) + Cells(I, 1).Value
                Case Else
                    '?
            End Select
```

I'm getting an error on this line:

```
varData(0, 2) = varData(0, 2) + Cells(I, 1).Value
```

saying "subscript out of range"

I also tried changing the array to

```
varData = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

Please help me understand how I'm out of range

Comment: What's in I when it fails?

Comment: What if you write a line of code that prints varData(0,2) ? Does that fail?

Comment: @nicomp I = 12, the first relevant line of data. When removed, the line with  `varData(0, 0)` is the one with the error

Comment: @nicomp `MsgBox (varData(0, 0))` produces the same error: subscript out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a shorthand of Evaluate and as such you are loading the array through the same mechanism as the sheet and as such the base is 1 not 0.

[image]

So you want to change the references as such:

```
       select Case sth
            Case "1"
                varData(1, 1) = varData(0, 0) + Cells(I, 1).Value
            Case "2"
                varData(1, 2) = varData(0, 1) + Cells(I, 1).Value
            Case "3"
                varData(1, 3) = varData(0, 2) + Cells(I, 1).Value
            Case "4"
                varData(1, 4) = varData(0, 3) + Cells(I, 1).Value
            Case "5"
                varData(1, 5) = varData(0, 4) + Cells(I, 1).Value
            Case Else
                '?
        End Select
```